# Unable to serve a model using CloudML: Error building/loading the model

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I followed the [following guide](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/custom-prediction-routines) to deploy a **custom prediction solution** to CloudML.

I created a bucket which contains my `model.pkl` and the custom code `custom_code.tar.gz`. I then proceed by deploying it on CloudML using the Web Interface, where I specify the required paths.

However, in the end, the model fails to build giving me very little information about the source of the error and how to fix it:

[image]

Comment: are you using the exact code from the tutorial, or have you modified it?  If you can share some code of your custom predictor, it may help to see what's wrong.  Also, what type of model are you using (tensorflow, keras, etc?).  Have you tried using the command line to create the model?

Comment: Agreed. Please include some code snippets, and gcloud commands that you used to create and deploy the model.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mention you are using Web to create your models, 
you can enable Logging during model creation using `gcloud` commands to debug in detail:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform models create {MODEL_NAME} \
 --regions {REGION} \
 --enable-logging \
 --enable-console-logging
```

From [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict#requesting_logs_for_online_prediction_requests):

> If you want to enable online prediction logging, you must configure it
>   when you create a model resource or when you create a model version
>   resource, depending on which type of logging you want to enable. There
>   are three types of logging, which you can enable independently:
>
> Access logging, which logs information like timestamp and latency for
>   each request to Stackdriver Logging.
>
> You can enable access logging when you create a model resource.
>
> Stream logging, which logs the stderr and stdout streams from your
>   prediction nodes to Stackdriver Logging, and can be useful for
>   debugging. This type of logging is in beta, and it is not supported by
>   Compute Engine (N1) machine types.
>
> You can enable stream logging when you create a model resource.
>
> Request-response logging, which logs a sample of online prediction
>   requests and responses to a BigQuery table. This type of logging is in
>   beta.
>
> You can enable request-response logging by creating a model version
>   resource, then updating that version.